# Certificate and Key Management

Tags: certificates, ssl

Currently I have a community that users have been successfully using for about a year.  The web address starts with https://...  There is a self signed certificate.  I don't remember creating this so I am guessing it was generated automatically.  A consulting company has suggested we get a Keystore certificate.  I am trying to understand why we would need this versus what we already have using Salesforce self signed certificate.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a certificate because was setting up a URL to point to a Salesforce URL.